Jmeter file upload issue without parameter name is failing
I'm trying post file upload in Jmeter and trying replicate image / doc upload which is testing in browser. I have tried multiple suggestions which are provided in community bu it seems something is missing ( I guess file name).
I have tried with below options,
Request:

Result:

I have tried file name to specify using browser but ther is no file name.

Please help me to resolve this error.

Just record your test scenario using HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder, it will generate appropriate HTTP Request sampler configuration
Before uploading make sure to copy the UploadNote.png file to bin folder of your JMeter installation, this way JMeter will be able to properly capture the request and build the relevant HTTP Request sampler configuration and HTTP Header Manager if required.
More information: JMeter Performance Testing: JMeter Download & Upload Scenarios
